# Remembering the remote desktop connection password

Tags: remote-desktop, passwords, windows-server-2008-r2

I have googled a little bit, but all I can find is a bunch of ways to recover password ON THE MACHINE that is beeing used (most of the times, performing a physical access to the machine).

My problem is: since 2013 I have been using the Windows Remote Desktop application to access to a remote (cloud) server of mine. 
No problem whatsoever, until today.

Today my every-day machine crashed, so I couldn't access to my Remote Desktop application anymore. What I did was to set up a similar environment on another machine of mine (a Mac). So after downloading the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from the App store, I tried to login....and...I couldn't remeber the password!!! 
I have always used the RD with auto-logon (i think it's called that way) and I cannot remember the password to connect to my machine.

I managed to repair my computer, so I did access to the cloud server with RD. I just wanted to change password for my admin user, so to set the new password on my MAC RD as well (and my Android RD as well).

Windows Server 2008 R2 let's me manage the user details, but when it comes to the password, it NEEDS the old password before changing credentials with the new one. But STILL I do not remember it.

Is there a place where my RD has stored the login details so I can perform some sort of "retrieve password"? I have no physical access to the remote machine as it is a cloud instance bought on Cloud.it, so I cannot use the "cd-drive or usb-drive solution".

Any help is highly appreciated. If my local machine crashes again, I really do not know how to reconnect to my remote server.

Thank you all.

Comment: An admin on the Server2k8r2 box can reset your password arbitrarilly, without need to provide the old password. please contact the administrator or hosting service.

Comment: I am the admin of the 2k8r2 box, but I have a very low knowledge of sysadmin. By the way, I HAVE REMEBERED THE PASSWORD 1 minute ago!!! Problem solved for me, but maybe it could be useful for other people to know how to change pwd as an admin. You mean using the net user command line instructions?

Comment: I have not used the following solution, because fortunately, after 42 attempts, I remembered the passwrd, but it could be useful for anyone else experiencing the same issue: https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/Cc771865.aspx